# Estou a desenvolver um jogo em as3 de memória?

Tags: actionscript-3

Queria saber como fazer um jogo de memoria em as3 onde primeiramente tenha:

1-toda a vez que o jogo seja executado as cartas estão aleatorias.
2-tenha pelo menos uma condição de verificar se as cartas são iguais e se forem para desaparecer.
3- se as cartas nao forem iguas voltam ao normal
4-tudo apenas com um movieclip que contenha nas frames as cartas

```
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;

 //variáveis relativo ao score, pattern and so on
 var pattern = new Array();
 var buttons = new Array();
 buttons.push(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p);
 var position = 0;

//Dizer aos botões que esperam ser clicados pelo rato
a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
c.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
d.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
e.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
f.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
g.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
h.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
i.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
j.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
k.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
l.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
m.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
n.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
o.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);
p.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Clicked);

function Clicked(clickInfo:MouseEvent){
trace("Clique");
switch(clickInfo.target){
case a:
    clickInfo.target.gotoAndStop(2);
break;
case b:
    clickInfo.target.gotoAndStop(3);
}
}
```

tenho isto na primeira frame do jogo

e tenho um movieclip que cotem 4 cartas (5 frames ex:1-com a borda, 2-5: com simbolos)

Comment: O que você já fez? Seria interessante adicionar o que já tentou na sua pergunta.

Comment: diegofm esta ai um update